# A query for merging date intervals

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a simple table with 3 columns:

```
(cid, from, to) -> (int, datetime, datetime)
```

The difference between `dateFrom` and `dateTo` should be >= 1 month. And unfortunately i have some corrupt data which do not satisfy this condition.

```
INPUT: 

An example data (cid - from - to) : 
8 - 01.05.2012 - 01.09.2012 
8 - 02.09.2012 - 10.09.2012 
8 - 11.09.2012 - 18.09.2012 
8 - 18.09.2012 - 02.10.2012 
8 - 03.10.2012 - 04.10.2013
```

DESIRED OUTPUT in a temp table:

I want to merge the dates whose interval is less than a month into 1 row:

```
8 - 01.05.2012 - 01.09.2012 
8 - 02.09.2012 - 02.10.2012 
8 - 03.10.2012 - 04.10.2013
```

So everything between 02.09.2012 - 02.10.2012 is merged into one row.

Is this possible using only T-SQL? (even without a cursor)

Comment: Please [do not cross post](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28863434/1387418). You can flag your question to be moved by moderators.

Comment: I deleted it from StackOverflow.

Comment: `01.05.2012 - 01.09.2012` is more than 1 month but left unchanged. The next 3 rows are all less than 1 month but are combined into 1 row. The last row is also less than 1 month but left unchanged. I think you should describe more carefully your criteria.

Comment: I am so sorry. I corrected the post. The difference must be greater than 1 month.

Comment: Still, `02.09.2012 - 02.10.2012` is only one month and the 5th row less than 1 month. Why are they not combined?

Comment: last row has 1 year

Comment: Also. Does an interval, like `02.09.2012 - 10.09.2012` include the last day (`10.09.2012`) or not? If not, there is a gap from `10.09.2012` to `11.09.2012` If yes, the day `18.09.2012` appears in two intervals.

Comment: Yes it includes. yes 18.09.2012 appears 2 times, because like i mentioned before, the data is corrupted because of our previous programmer and i have to fix it somehow.

Comment: OK, I missed the 2013 in the last row. But still there is not a clear rule about what should happen in some cases. Say there are 2 rows, with `01.05.2010 - 01.09.2010` and `01.09.2010 - 10.09.2010` and no more rows in that September. Should they be combined or left as they are?

Comment: In that case they should be left as they are.

Comment: Only rows which are less than a month should be merged if it is possible. For example 18.10.2010 - 27.10.2010 and 28.10.2010 - 05.11.2010 should be merged into 18.10.2010 - 05.11.2010.

Comment: Which version of SQL-Server are you using? This is a gaps-and-islands problem and for 2012+ versions, it will be easier to write.

Comment: The version is 2008

Comment: +1 for the expressing the name of the problem so i can search in google more precisly

Answer (score 1):

I think what you'll need to do is create another temp table that has the same columns but with an identity column so you can use it for joining purposes.  I also noticed that your date format had day.month.year which threw me off initially....

This will get you pretty close:

```
create table newtable ( cid int, fromdate datetime, todate datetime)
go

insert into dbo.newtable
values
(8 , '05/01/2012', '09/01/2012'), 
(8 , '09/02/2012', '09/10/2012'),
(8 , '09/11/2012', '09/18/2012'),
(8 , '09/18/2012', '10/02/2012'),
(8 , '10/03/2012', '10/04/2013')


create table dbo.newtable2 (newIdent int identity(1,1), cid int, fromdate datetime, todate datetime, targetdate datetime)

insert into dbo.newtable2 (cid, fromdate, todate, targetdate)
select cid, fromdate, todate, dateadd(m, 1, fromdate) from dbo.newtable


select cid, fromdate, todate from newtable2 where todate > targetdate

union

select cid, min(fromdate), max(todate) from newtable2 where newident in
(
select a.newident
from newtable2 a inner join newtable2 b on dateadd(m, 1, a.fromdate) > b.fromdate and a.newident = b.newident
where 
a.todate <= a.targetdate
order by a.fromdate
)
group by cid
```

The nested select is sorted by fromdate so you will get merged records in consecutive rows so that you can leverage MIN and MAX functions.

The only thing is the UNION will not have the rows sorted but you can always dump that into another temp table and then sort it.

Comment: Thx i will check your answer tomorrow

Answer (score 0):

```
create table #test ( cid int, fromdt datetime , todt datetime)

insert into #test values
(8,'05-01-2012','09-01-2012'),
(8,'09-02-2012','09-10-2012'),
(8,'09-11-2012','09-18-2012'),
(8,'09-18-2012','10-02-2012'),
(8,'10-03-2012','10-04-2013') 


;with cte as
(select cid, fromdt, todt, row_number() over(order by fromdt) -
            ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by datepart(mm, fromdt) order by datepart(mm, fromdt)) grp from #test)
select cid, min(fromdt), max(todt) from cte
group by cid,grp
```

Comment: The `;` is called statement terminator. It should **terminate"** (go at the end of) every statement, not before of some of them.